# Can Solr remove documents that correspond with rows that have been removed from a database, without doing a clean full import?

Tags: solr

I have a solr collection that performs periodic delta imports every 20 minutes to retrieve newly added rows from a huge postgres db. this is configured in the data import handler, like so:

```xml
<document>
    <entity name="myEntity"
            query="select * from test_view"
            deltaImportQuery= "select * from test_view WHERE x_id= ${dih.delta.x_id}"
            deltaQuery="SELECT x_id from test_view
                where time_entered &gt; '${dih.last_index_time}'"
            >
      <field column="x_id" name="id"/>
      ...
```

full imports are not viable to run frequently because of the database size.

this now has the added functionality of removing old rows every 20 minutes.

how can i get my collection to also remove the documents which now no longer exist in the database without performing a full import with the clean flag? I assume that a delta import with the clean flag will only add the new rows that are being imported, removing everything else.

Comment: You need to track your entries using logical deletes in that case, or have a separate table that tracks ids that have been deleted; there is no functionality in DIH that compares what is in the database to what is in the index. Depending on the number of documents/rows, it might be effective enough to implement it yourself (fetch every id with the `/export` handler, then select all ids from the database, compare and issue deletes).

Comment: After exporting the id's from solr, how would I go about comparing these to the id's in the db and issuing deletes? The id's are randomized essentially, therefore if I am issuing deletes by a url request, would I have to run a request for every document I delete?

Comment: You can run a delete by query - `id:(id1 OR id2 OR id3 OR id4 OR id5)` - comparing them against the db would be issuing a `SELECT id FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, ...)`, then removing all the returned ids. Batch the queries to avoid sending in millions of ids in IN (...).

Comment: thanks @MatsLindh, this has been very helpful - the IN equivalent in solr is great.